# Next.js Styling - Footer component for some reason is not at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Next.js Styling - Footer component for some reason is not at the bottom of the screen?

```
import Head from "next/head";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const layoutStyle = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%"
};

const Layout = props => (
  <div className="Layout" style={layoutStyle}>
    <Head>
      <title>Oracle</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    </Head>
    <Navbar />
    <div>{props.children}</div>


    <Footer/>
  </div>

);
```

export default Layout;

footer

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";


class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="bg-gray-100">
                <div className="bg-gray-100 container mx-auto px-6 pt-10 pb-6" >
                    >
                    © Oracle Corp. All rights reserved.
        </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Footer;
```

I know this is something to do with next.js, but unsure how to fix : /

I think has something to do with how next sets up each page?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Instead of `height: 100%`, can you change it to `min-height: 100vh`?

Comment: since you are using flex, you can either use `margin-top:auto` on the footer or add `flex-grow:1` to the page wrapper

Comment: The issue with flex on an application like next is next adds an extra element that disrupts the full height and or flex stretch values. Inspect the HTML and you will see an element with a class of _next or similar. You need to make sure you are applying the appropriate height and or flex to properties to that as well. You can absolutely do the flex box sticky footer without doing absolute position. Is the goal to do a sticky footer that is at the bottom when there is not enough content? Or are you trying to have the footer always visible regardless of amount of content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue and move `footer` to bottom of page by adding an inline style to `Footer` component of `style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width:"100%" }}`. The component would look like:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";

class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width:"100%" }} className="bg-gray-100">
        <div className="bg-gray-100 container mx-auto px-6 pt-10 pb-6">
          > © Oracle Corp. All rights reserved.
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

Comment: This sort of worked, except thefooter is now a little rectangle that goes into the corner lol!

Comment: And also, when using mobile version, it does not stay at the bottom (Looking at Apple s5 view).

Comment: I added the `width:"100%"` property to inline style that should allow it to cover full bottom.

Comment: For some reason, when scrolling past first page, the footer is not moving?

Comment: Life saver answer

Answer (score 9):

Try modifying the `__next` div that wraps the application.

[image]

```css
#__next {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (
  <div style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0, width:"100%" }} className="bg-gray-100">
    <div className="bg-gray-100 container mx-auto px-6 pt-10 pb-6">
      > © Oracle Corp. All rights reserved.
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

in nextjs 'pages/_app.js' adds a global style for its `<div class="container">` ...

```
        <style jsx global>
          {`

            .container {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              min-height: 100vh;
            }

          `}
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who put their components inside src (or any other name) folder, make sure to edit your Tailwind config file.
before :

```
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

after

```
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

This was my issue !